# NavigationView pushing List row separators to the right in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

When I wrap a List with a NavigationView the list row separators are pushed to the right:

[image]

```
struct NumbersList: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Text("One")
      Text("Two")
      Text("Three")
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NumbersList()
    }
}
```

Compared to when I do not wrap the List in a NavigationView:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    NumbersList()
  }
}
```

How can I place a List in a NavigationView without its list row separators being pushed to the right?

Comment: you could try adding: `.listStyle(.plain)` to the `List`. There is also a `.listRowSeparator(...)` that could be used.

Comment: Which version of iOS and Xcode are you running? I ran your code and got the expected results (with the `NavigationView`) on a physical iPhone 8 running iOS 15.2. Xcode is 13.1

Comment: @ThisuraDodangoda I'm using iOS 15.2 and Xcode 13.2.1. When I execute the code on a physical iPhone 8 I still get the unexpected malalignment. I was able to circumvent the problem by using a Form, which renders as expected, instead of a List.